# Instagram not allowing me to show my latest images on my website via their API

Tags: instagram

I want to show my latest 8 photos in my website's footer.
So, I created an Instagram client, got an access token and pulled only images from my profile while developing my website on localhost.
Here's the JavaScript code by which I show the photos in my website's footer.

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token={my_access_token}&count=8',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        var images = data.data;
        for(i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            $('section.instagram-feed').append('<div class="feed-image" style="background-image: url(' + images[i].images.low_resolution.url +');"><a href="' + images[i].link + '" target="_blank"></a></div>');
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Eventually, about 95 photos of my profile got deleted and the client I registered was blocked due to *violating the Instagram Platform Policies.*
This made me really confused:

- In their platform policy, they state that " 16. Don't use the
  Instagram API to **simply display User Content**, import or backup
  content, or manage Instagram relationships, without our prior
  permission. "
- If you go to your client -> Permissions -> Start a submission ->
  click on the " **I want to display my Instagram posts on my
  website.** " checkbox, you get this following message " You do **not
  need to submit for review for this use case**. If you are a developer
  and you want to display Instagram content on your website, then you
  do not need to submit your app for review. By using a client in
  sandbox mode, you can still access the last 20 media of any sandbox
  user that grants you permission..... "

So, am I allowed to show my own Instagram photos on my own website or not?
If so, why were about 95 photos of my profile deleted, and why did my client get blocked from out of nowhere?
What am I doing wrong here?

[image: Client deactivated]

[image: Instagram submission]

[image: Instagram Policy no 16]

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  It's just happened to my sandbox app that does the same thing too..

Comment: same probleme and i can't find a solution